# DHIS2 and mysql?

Tags: dhis-2

The DHIS2 documentation mentions that it supports mysql (https://docs.dhis2.org/2.28/en/implementer/html/installation.html), however thats the last point mysql is ever mentioned.

Does the current version really support mysql? If it does, will GIS still work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. First of all it is recommended to use postgres.
2. Secondly most of the testing and QA is done on instances with postgres.
3. Thirdly POST GIS extension is available only in postgres , which can cause a hurdle for you at later stage.
4. Fourthly , the GIS data points and boundaries are stored in a format which is better handled in postgres db structure.

Therefore please go with postgres and chill

Comment: actually I found it really couldn't cope with having cases inserted by location.. the API at the time was not setup for external injection of this. :) Its been a while since this call was open though :)

Answer (score 2):

From direct dhis2 support email...

Up until and including version 2.28, mysql should work.

However, from version 2.29 we require PostgreSQL as the database platform, together with the PostGIS spatial extension. This means that MySQL is no longer supported.

The minimum version required is PostgreSQL 9.1. However we recommend upgrading to a later version as we plan to take advantage of some of the useful features part of PostgreSQL 10 such as logical replication and native partitioning in future versions of DHIS 2.